# NVM: command not found but present in .bashrc

Tags: node.js, bash, nvm

I'm trying to install nvm on my Mac OS (according to https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation)

I'm running

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.27.1/install.sh | bash
```

I see that my .bashrc contains

```
export NVM_DIR="/Users/yanamikhaylenko/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

However when I run

```
nvm install node && nvm alias default node
```

I receive

```
-bash: nvm: command not found
```

Should I export path in .profile or do something else?

Please, note that I'm using Node.js v 4.1.1

Comment: Did you recently edit your .bashrc? If so, you need to `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I didn't change it. It helped me to run nvm install node && nvm alias default node. However when I opened new terminal window and type nvm --help it says again -bash: nvm: command not found

Comment: That's new information (open a new terminal) -- If your terminal launches a *login* shell, you should put `[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc` in your `~/.bash_profile`file (or ~/.profile, whichever you use) -- see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files